# How to select IDs that have at least two specific instaces in a given column

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I'm working with a medical claim table in pyspark and I want to return only userid's that have at least 2 claim_ids. My table looks something like this:

```
claim_id |  userid |  diagnosis_type |  claim_type
__________________________________________________
1            1            C100            M
2            1            C100a           M
3            2            D50             F
5            3            G200            M
6            3            C100            M
7            4            C100a           M
8            4            D50             F
9            4            A25             F
```

From this example, I would want to return userid's 1, 3, and 4 only. Currently I'm building a temp table to count all of the distinct instances of the claim_ids

```
create table temp.claim_count as
select distinct userid, count(distinct claim_id) as claims
from medical_claims
group by userid
```

and then pulling from this table when the number of claim_id >1

```
select distinct userid
from medical_claims
where userid (
    select distinct userid
    from temp.claim_count
    where claims>1)
```

Is there a better / more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Just use `group by` and `having`... `select userid from table group by userid having count(distinct claimid) > 1`

Comment: I'm assuming you have indexes on columns you're running counts on. Have you tried GROUP BY userid HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ? [check this out](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-having.php) BTW  please use all caps for statements like SELECT, FROM, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only the ids, then use `group by`:

```
select userid, count(*) as claims
from medical_claims
group by userid
having count(*) > 1;
```

If you want the original rows, then use window functions:

```
select mc.*
from (select mc.*, count(*) over (partition by userid) as num_claims
      from medical_claims mc
     ) mc
where num_claims > 1;
```